# Подсчет значений в разных столбцах csv файла по заданному условию

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Открываем все лежащие в папке csv файлы. Затем суммируем два столбца в каждом файле. Отбираем только один день недели по всем датам (например Понедельники). После этого, нужно ввести еще отбор по некоему условию, например по столбцу Time и отсеять значения скажем по "1500". То есть отсортировали Понедельники, потом по 1500, а оставшийся результат сохранили в  файл csv.

Собственно не хватает строки, по которой можно отобрать значения в Time.

```css
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

a = r'C:/Users/II/Downloads/*.csv' # открытие файла (выдает ошибку)

files = glob.glob(a)

for f in files:
    a = pd.read_csv(f, index_col='Date', encoding='latin1', parse_dates=['Date'])
    a['total'] = a['Open'] + a['Close'] # прибавляем однин столбец данных к другому и получаем total
    a = a.loc[a.index.weekday == 0, ['total']].sort_values('total') # если сортировку делать не надо, убираем sort_values('total')

    new_fn ='{0[0]}_total{0[1]}'.format(os.path.splitext(f))
    a.to_csv(new_fn)
```

Пример данных:

```css
Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2016-01-04,1400,102.610001,105.370003,102.0,105.349998,67649400.0,102.612183
2016-01-04,1500,105.75,105.849998,102.410004,102.709999,55791000.0,100.04079200000001
2016-01-04,1600,100.559998,102.370003,99.870003,100.699997,68457400.0,98.083025
2016-01-04,1700,98.68,100.129997,96.43,96.449997,81094400.0,93.943473
2016-01-04,1800,98.550003,99.110001,96.760002,96.959999,70798000.0,94.44022199999999
2016-01-04,1900,98.970001,99.059998,97.339996,98.529999,49739400.0,95.96942
2016-01-04,2000,100.550003,100.690002,98.839996,99.959999,49154200.0,97.362258
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** проблема была в том, что `Date` - это не обычный столбец, а индекс, поэтому обращаться к нему нужно соответственно:

```
for f in files:
    a = pd.read_csv(f, index_col='Date', encoding='latin1', parse_dates=['Date'])
    a = a.loc[(a.index.weekday == 0) & (a.Time == 1000)]
    new_fn ='{0[0]}_total{0[1]}'.format(os.path.splitext(f))
    a.to_csv(new_fn)
```

---

**Старый ответ**: подразумевает, что `Date` - столбец типа `datetime64`

Исходные данные:

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
        Date  Time        Open        High         Low       Close      Volume   Adj Close
0 2016-01-04  1400  102.610001  105.370003  102.000000  105.349998  67649400.0  102.612183
1 2016-01-04  1500  105.750000  105.849998  102.410004  102.709999  55791000.0  100.040792
2 2016-01-04  1600  100.559998  102.370003   99.870003  100.699997  68457400.0   98.083025
3 2016-01-04  1700   98.680000  100.129997   96.430000   96.449997  81094400.0   93.943473
4 2016-01-04  1800   98.550003   99.110001   96.760002   96.959999  70798000.0   94.440222
5 2016-01-04  1900   98.970001   99.059998   97.339996   98.529999  49739400.0   95.969420
6 2016-01-04  2000  100.550003  100.690002   98.839996   99.959999  49154200.0   97.362258
```

Решение:

```
In [73]: df.loc[(df.Date.dt.weekday == 0) & (df.Time == 1500)]
Out[73]:
        Date  Time    Open        High         Low       Close      Volume   Adj Close
1 2016-01-04  1500  105.75  105.849998  102.410004  102.709999  55791000.0  100.040792
```

Если надо сохранить в CSV:

```
df.loc[(df.Date.dt.weekday == 0) & (df.Time == 1500)].to_csv('/path/to/file.csv', ...)
```

Данное решение ожидает, что тип столбца `Time`: `int`:

```
In [74]: df.dtypes
Out[74]:
Date         datetime64[ns]
Time                  int64  # !!!
Open                float64
High                float64
Low                 float64
Close               float64
Volume              float64
Adj Close           float64
dtype: object
```

Если `Time` строка, то:

```
df.loc[(df.Date.dt.weekday == 0) & (df.Time == '1500')].to_csv('/path/to/file.csv', ...)
```

Comment: @Alex,не могу найти что и где вы написали?

Comment: @Alex, я исправил ответ - так работает?